# If I add a non-Steam game to my Steam account can I then play it on any PC?

Tags: steam

On my family PC there are lots of games, If I add them to my Steam account can I then play them on my laptop? Would I only be able to play on the PC they were on?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All that adding them to Steam does is allows you to launch them through Steam (and you will be shown as playing a non-Steam game to any friends you have). It doesn't allow them to be downloaded to or played on any other machine. Even if they were Steam games, you'd still have to download them from your library to the other machine to play, but non-Steam games don't allow for this.

Comment: Just to add to this: some boxed games do come with keys that work on Steam. If a CD Key is attached, and that game has a Steam Store page, then it will be shareable.

Comment: @NBN-Alex yes, but then they become Steam games, not non-Steam games.

Comment: true, just a side note since the "non-steam" could be games that where bought outside of Steam, with an older key that wasn't designated for Steam. (Like the older Valve games published by Serria Games)

Comment: This answer is confusing. I bought some older games, some of which eventually appeared on Steam. If I link these non-Steam games (since I didn't buy them on Steam), will Steam add them to my library or not?